# How to get Fabric to fail instead of password prompt for "pubkey denied"?

Tags: python, fabric

When I use Fabric to connect to a host with the wrong SSH key, it prompts for a password instead of failing.

Here is the output from SSH:

```
$ ssh -i 'ssh_key_file' user@host
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

And here is what Fabric does with the following file:

```
# fabfile.py
from fabric.api import env, execute, run, task

env.hosts = ['host']
env.key_filename = 'ssh_key_file'

@task
def do_something():
    run('echo hello')

execute(do_something)
```

Fabric's output:

```
$ python fabfile.py
[104.236.30.93] Executing task 'do_something'
[104.236.30.93] run: echo hello
[104.236.30.93] Login password for 'deploy':
```

How can I get Fabric to fail immediately with preferably a `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).` error message, instead of prompting for a password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also affects other prompts (like the one for entering `env.host_string`) but you can do this with the `env.abort_on_prompts = True` (`--abort_on_prompts`).

When Fabric aborts on a prompt, it throws the built-in `SystemExit` exception that can be caught in case the programmer wants to select another SSH key or username to login with.

See the [env documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html).